# SQL: Deleting duplicate records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I have an sql server database, that I pre-loaded with a ton of rows of data.

Unfortunately, there is no primary key in the database, and there is now duplicate information in the table.  I'm not concerned about there not being a primary key, but i am concerned about there being duplicates in the database...

Any thoughts?  (Forgive me for being an sql server newb)

Comment: Well, howdo you determine a duplicate?

Comment: http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=Deleting+duplicate+records+in+SQL+Server

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using ? 2000, 2005, 2008 ?

Comment: "I am not concerned with having shot myself in my foot, but I am concerned with all the blood on the floor"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, this is one reason why you should have a primary key on the table.  What version of SQL Server?  For SQL Server 2005 and above:

```
;WITH r AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, -- whatever columns make a "unique" row
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY col1)
    FROM dbo.SomeTable
)
DELETE r WHERE rn > 1;
```

Then, so you don't have to do this again tomorrow, and the next day, and the day after that, declare a primary key on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table is unique by COL1 and COL2.
Here is a way to do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT COL1, COL2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, COL2 ORDER BY COL1, COL2 ASC) AS ROWID
      FROM TABLE_NAME )T
WHERE T.ROWID > 1
```

The ROWID > 1 will enable you to select only the duplicated rows.