# How to eliminiate duplicates rows in table of sql server 2005 database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i am using sql server 2005. i have a table contains duplicated rows. how can i eliminated those duplicate rows in that table? for e.g., the table may contain 3 similar rows in which i want to delete 2 rows and keep the original

Comment: Please **search** first before posting a question - this has been asked over and over and over again -

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Deleting duplicate records in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772592/sql-deleting-duplicate-records-in-sql-server)

Comment: marc_s that link helps me a lot

Comment: Get more lots http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows Looks like ppl like to hate duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to eliminate duplicate records from your result set, you can use the DISTINCT command:

```
SELECT DISTINCTI field1, field2 FROM...
```

If you want to delete those duplicate records, you can use COUNT to detect which records have more than one instance, and then deleting them with a subquery

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: the action you said above will delete all the duplicated rows but 1 want to keep one

Comment: Not if you use MAX(id) in the subquery to return you just the first id instance

Comment: Using a DISTINCT may be a lot more expensive than using the CTE method above with a large dataset or wide table.

Answer (score 0):

First you can copy duplicate record into another table like as following way

```
Select fieldnames into #temp from table1 group by fieldnames having count (*) > 1
```

then remove that record from original table

```
delete from table1 where fieldname in (select fieldnames from #temp)
```

and finally copy record from temporary table to original source table.

```
insert table1 select * from #temp
```

through above mentioned steps you can eliminate duplicate record from table.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding purpose, lets take a simple table Employee with below schema

```
EmployeeId - int
EmployeeName    varchar(50)
Age int
```

Lets populate with duplicate values. Please note primary key is not duplicated in this case

```
INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) VALUES (1,'Mark',20)
INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) VALUES (2,'Tom',22)
INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) VALUES (3,'Sam',24)
INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) VALUES (4,'Mark',20)
INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) VALUES (5,'Tom',22)
INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) VALUES (6,'Tom',22)
GO
```

we can make use of CTE in finding the  duplicate rows.
Gather duplicate rows by using Group by/Count statement.
Once Duplicate rows are Identified, we select those rows from the main table using join condition.
Now rank those Rows and delete all the rows apart from the rows with rank 1.
I find this a lot more elegant.

```
WITH TotalDuplicates(EmployeeName,Age,Total) AS 
(
    SELECT EmployeeName,Age,COUNT(employeeId)  AS Total  FROM Employee 
    GROUP BY EmployeeName,Age
    HAVING COUNT(employeeId) > 1
)
,DistinctRows(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age) AS 
(
    SELECT E.EmployeeId,E.EmployeeName,E.Age FROM Employee AS E
    INNER JOIN TotalDuplicates AS D 
    ON (E.EmployeeName = D.EmployeeName AND E.Age = D.Age)
)
,OrderedDuplicateTables(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Age,Ranking) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        EmployeeId,
        EmployeeName,
        Age,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeName, Age ORDER BY EmployeeId DESC) 
    FROM DistinctRows 
)

DELETE FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT EmployeeId FROM OrderedDuplicateTables WHERE Ranking > 1)
```